# Cannot get string data to pass through NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to achieve bi-directional, named pipe communication on my Win-XP workstation using two simple C# forms solutions. One for the client and one for the server. They appear almost identical and use NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream (.NET 3.5). Both client and server are set to bidirectional comms via **PipeDirection.InOut**

The order of start-up events is:
1) Start the server. It waits for a connection from the client.
2) Start the client and it immediately finds and connects to the server. The server, likewise, completes its connection to the client.
3) Both client and server launch their "Read" threads which in turn create instances of streamreader. These threads then call ReadLn() and block - waiting for data. In all instances, autoflush is true.

I then use streamwriter.WriteLn() to send string data from the server to the client (or vice-versa). However, the execution never returns from that call. I don't know why and any insights would be greatfully received.

I have spent considerable time studying all that there is on this subject but I'm still missing something.

Client and server code snippets are shown:

SERVER:

```
   private void ListenForClients()
    {
        // Only one server as this will be a 1-1 connection
        m_pipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1);

        // Wait for a client to connect
        m_pipeServerStream.WaitForConnection();

        // Ccould not create handle - server probably not running
        if (!m_pipeServerStream.IsConnected)
            return;

        // Create a stream writer which flushes after every write
        m_pipeServerWriter = new StreamWriter(m_pipeServerStream);
        m_pipeServerWriter.AutoFlush = true;

        Connected = true;

        // Start listening for messages
        if (m_pipeServerStream.CanRead)
        {
            ReadThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Read));
            ReadThread.Start(m_pipeServerStream);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from the client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverObj"></param>
    private void Read(object serverObj)
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = (NamedPipeServerStream)serverObj;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string buffer;
                try
                {
                    buffer = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //read error has occurred
                    break;
                }

                //client has disconnected
                if (buffer.Length == 0)
                    break;

                //fire message received event
                if (MessageReceived != null)
                {
                    MessageReceived(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a message to the connected client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">the message to send</param>
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        if (m_pipeServerWriter != null)
        {
            m_pipeServerWriter.WriteLine(message);
            m_pipeServerWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
```

CLIENT:

```
   private void ConnectToServer()
    {
        // Seek out the one server
        m_pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);

        // Connect to the waiting server
        m_pipeClientStream.Connect();

        // Ccould not create handle - server probably not running
        if (!m_pipeClientStream.IsConnected)
            return;

        // Create a stream writer which flushes after every write
        m_pipeClientWriter = new StreamWriter(m_pipeClientStream);
        m_pipeClientWriter.AutoFlush = true;

        Connected = true;

        // Start listening for messages
        if (m_pipeClientStream.CanRead)
        {
            ReadThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Read));
            ReadThread.Start(m_pipeClientStream);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from the server
    /// </summary>
    private void Read(object serverObj)
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = (NamedPipeClientStream)serverObj;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string buffer;
                try
                {
                    buffer = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //read error has occurred
                    break;
                }

                //client has disconnected
                if (buffer.Length == 0)
                    break;

                //fire message received event
                if (MessageReceived != null)
                {
                    MessageReceived(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a message to the connected server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        if (m_pipeClientWriter != null)
        {
            m_pipeClientWriter.WriteLine(message);
            m_pipeClientWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why Write never returned?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the Async flag on the streams:

NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

Answer (score 2):

I've now given up and moved to the safe, obvious technique of using two pipes, one for each direction of communication. They work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but I am also experiencing the same problem. First of all, I don't know why any reference to m_pipeServerStream.IsConnected will break the pipe. I tested this with just a simple MessageBox.Show(m_pipeServerStream.IsConnected.ToString()) and that broke my pipe!

Secondly, another weird thing is that your streamreader call will never return if you are using a duplex named pipe. You will need to read it manually like this

```
    const int BufferSize = 4096;
    Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = new char[BufferSize];
    byte[] bytes = new byte[BufferSize];
    int numBytes = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("before do while loop");
    numBytes = pipeServer.Read(bytes, 0, BufferSize);
    if (numBytes > 0)
    {
        int numChars = decoder.GetCharCount(bytes, 0, numBytes);
        decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, numBytes, chars, 0, false);
        msg.Append(chars, 0, numChars);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(numBytes.ToString() + " " + msg.ToString());

    MessageBox.Show("Finished reading, now starting writing");
    using (StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(pipeServer))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sending ok back");
        swr.WriteLine("OK");
        pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
    }
```

Anyway, it doesn't seem to like the behavior of StreamReader, but this will work for now... I got this off this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/23dc2951-8b59-48e4-89fe-d2b435db48c6/

I'm not following every single step because I just needed to find out why it keeps hanging at StreamReader.ReadLine(). it's not returning from this function. StreamWriter does not seem to have this problem.

I am actually communicating between native dll and a managed windows service. Imagine my surprise when I found out that it was the managed part that was the problem, not the unmanaged part since they has such good examples in msdn...

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on Named Pipes or Anonymous Pipes but I will give it my best shot at trying to help others out even though you have a work around to your problem.

Client Server Communications is the best way to think of how this process should be achieved.

Server Starts and Listens for a Connection --> Client initiates a connection to a Server -->Server accepts the connection -->Client makes a request -->Server makes a response --> Connection is closed.

[image]

Server Starts and Listens for a Connection:

```
try
{
namedPipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

// Wait for a connection here...
namedPipeServerStream.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(ConnectionCallBack), namedPipeServerStream);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Client Connects, then makes a Request:

```
try
{
namedPipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

// Connect with timeout...
namedPipeClientStream.Connect(TimeOut);

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DataToSend);
namedPipeClientStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ConnectionCallBack, namedPipeClientStream);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

ConnectionCallBack is an Asynchronous CallBack. This Method (this is on the Client) is where the Connection is managed:

```
private void ConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iAsyncResult)
{
try
{
// Get the pipe
NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClientStream = (NamedPipeClientStream)iAsyncResult.AsyncState;

// End the write
namedPipeClientStream.EndWrite(iAsyncResult);
namedPipeClientStream.Flush();

// Get Server Response...
GetServerResponse(namedPipeClientStream);

// Flush Data and Close Pipe...
namedPipeClientStream.Flush();
namedPipeClientStream.Close();
namedPipeClientStream.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
```

The Server handles the Client Request and formulates a Response and sends it:

```
// Response Methods...
public void SendResponse(string ServerResponse)
{
try
{
// Fill Buffer with Server Response Data...
byte[] Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerResponse);

// Begin Async Write to the Pipe...
namedPipeServerStream.BeginWrite(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SendResponseCallBack, namedPipeServerStream);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}

private void SendResponseCallBack(IAsyncResult iAsyncResult)
{
try
{
// Get the Pipe Handle...
NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServerStream = (NamedPipeServerStream)iAsyncResult.AsyncState;

// End the Write and Flush...
namedPipeServerStream.EndWrite(iAsyncResult);
namedPipeServerStream.Flush();

// Close the Connection and Dispose...
namedPipeServerStream.Close();
namedPipeServerStream.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
```

This is called from the Client Request Handler:

```
private void ClientRequestHandler(string clientRequest)
{
try
{
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
this.Invoke(new InvokedDelegate(ClientRequestHandler), clientRequest);
}
else
{
ProcessClientRequest(clientRequest);
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}

private void ProcessClientRequest(string clientRequest)
{
// Display the Client Request...
richTextBox1.Text = clientRequest;

PipeServer.SendResponse("Server has received Client Request at: " + DateTime.Now);
}
```

The Client has initiated a Connection to the Server, at the point where the Asynchronous CallBack Method see's this:

```
// Get Server Response...
GetServerResponse(namedPipeClientStream);
```

The Connection is still open. The Client Request was made and the Pipe was Flushed and is ready for the Client to Read the Server Response mentioned above:

```
private void GetServerResponse(NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClientStream)
{
byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
namedPipeClientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

// Convert byte buffer to string
string ResponseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

// Pass message back to calling form
ServerResponse.Invoke(ResponseData);
}
```

The Response is received and then the Connection is again Flushed and Closed ready for the Client to Initiate another Connection.

The code is a little more complex than just this but essentially this is how it works. While you have a connection initiated, use it. Once you close it, and then try to re-initialise it, you will need to wait for a period of time for it to dispose properly or you will get all sorts of semaphore errors and so on. Don't Smoke your connection when you don't need to!!!

Please see: [Code Project - **C# Async Named Pipes for an excellent example**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492231/Csharp-Async-Named-Pipes)